# How to make the background of a button change on mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, button, background, mouseover

In the following code, I want to make a blue image background button change to a green image button on mouse over.

My XAML code is below, but nothing happens on mouse over the button.
`NextButton.png` is the original button and `nextGreen.png` is supposed to be the background on mouse over.

Where is the problem ?

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
        Content=""
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Margin="0,0,0.2,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Width="50"
        Height="100"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Click="Next_Click">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="NextButton.png" />
    </Button.Background>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="nextGreen.png" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Nextbutton.png"/>
                </StackPanel.Background>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: ......................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the background of the button but then you override the `Template` so the `Button.Background` never shows. You should get rid of `Button.Background` and then name the `StackPanel` in the `Template` so that you can change the background in the `Trigger`.

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0.2,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Height="100" Grid.Column="1" Click="Next_Click">
   <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="root">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="nextGreen.png" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <StackPanel x:Name="root">
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Nextbutton.png"/>
                </StackPanel.Background>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks  alot evanb 
it works 
only a little change in your code

 <StackPanel x:Name="root">
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Nextbutton.png"/>
                </StackPanel.Background>
            </StackPanel>

Should be exisit before controltemplate so it can identifiy "root" name 

thanks a lot